# Почему — на постном масле?

Tags: фразеология

Когда говорят о чем-то незначительном, то называют его ерунда или чепуха на постном масле. Насколько я помню, "чепуха" — это какое-то блюдо. Но "ерунда"-то нет. Но почему оба они — на постном масле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все комментаторы согласны, что "ерунда на постном масле" вторична по отношению к аналогичному выражению с чепухой, поэтому стоит сперва разобраться именно с эти выражением.

Само слово чепуха относят или к щепе/чепе. То есть Чепуха - это щепуха, мусор. Или как Виноградов к чепь/цеп и тогда чепуха - это опять-таки мелкий мусор, получающийся после молотьбы. Вариант Виноградова менее вероятен, так как слово "чепуха" есть только в русском языке, и появилось сравнительно поздно (вторая половина XVIII века) что вряд ли возможно для результата столь важного и всюду распространённого процесса. К тому же "деревянная" этимология вообще хорошо ложиться в русскую семантику глупости: вздор/задир на дереве, чушь/чушка, чурка, дубина и пр.

Теперь, по поводу постного масла. Тоже 2 варианта. Или как показатель полной второсортности этой чепухи, или какое-то блюдо-чепуха, сделанное на масле. Оба понимания слова чепуха, допускают и то и другое толкование.
 Единственное, если речь идёт о блюде, то до 1765 года речь могла идти только о блюде из щепок репы. Если кому доводилось очищать репу от кожицы, то думаю он заметил, что в отличии от лент картофельной кожуры, срезается репин верхний слой мелкими щепами. Щепы эти после термической обработки, например обжарки на растительном масле, вполне пригодны в пищу. Аппетита правда подобное блюдо, лично у меня, не вызывает. В этом случае вполне логично, что с уходом репы из рациона крестьян блюдо "чепуха", тоже должно было исчезнуть.

Comment: Репа - это да. Весьма правдоподобно.  
Уточните, если не трудно, две вещи:  
Что за два варианта по поводу постного масла. Второсортность??? 
Что за дата 1865-й? В смысле репы.

Comment: @behemothus, дата скорей не в смысле репы, а в смысле картошки. До 1765  (1865 - опечатка) года картофель в России употребляли редко, в основном иностранцы. В 1765 к нам была завезена крупная партия семенной картошки, которая постепенно стала заменять репу в русской кухне. Выращиваемых крестьянами злаков было меньше, чем необходимо для удовлетворения биологической потребности в еде, поэтому до конца XVIII века репа была незаменимым источником калорий. Начиная с 1765 репу в этом значении стала постепенно вытеснять картошка.

По поводу 2 версий, да, второсортность вообще, или конкретное блюдо.

Comment: >До 1765 (1865 - опечатка)  
  
Тогда вопрос снимается.
Да, согласен, Екатерина, картофельные бунты...
А то я уж про крепостное право чего подумал ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Чепуха на постном масле** – неодобр. о чем-либо не заслуживающем внимания, о глупых рассуждениях. Фразеологизм собственно русский. Чепуха – того же корня, что и щепа (от несохранившегося чепа). Первоначально имелись в виду нащипанные мелкие ломтики картофеля или каких-либо других овощей, поджаренные на постном масле. Вариант ерунда на постном масле является вторичным.
См.http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/phrases/?alpha=%D7

Answer (score 1):

На постном масле (растительное - подсолнечное, кукурузное и т.п.)  еда, наверно, не очень вкусная и сытная получалась, тем более просто овощи. С трудом могу себе представить, как от картошки можно что-то отщепить без вспомогательных средств. Если только капусту еще пощипать можно. Или картошка вареная?

Comment: Картошка получила распространение в России только в конце XVIII века. По виду, чепуха слово более древнее (у классиков "чепу" не встречал), так что картошка требованию историзма не соответствует явно. Вместо картошки выращивали репу, и настоящая чепуха делалась по видимому из неё.

Постное масло того времени - конопляное на юге или льняное на севере. И то, и другое вкус блюда не улучшают.  Кукурузу не выращивали вовсе, а выжимать масло из подсолнуха наши крестьяне догадались только в XIX веке.

Comment: Я просто примеры привела постного масла, но здесь, согласна, к образованию выражения они не подойдут. Льняное масло пробовала. Горьковатое. В еду точно не добавила бы.   

Вариант образования слова "чепуха", притянутый за уши, но все же... У В. Даля в словаре дается статья на слово "чепуха". Кроме тех значений, которые здесь уже обсуждали, проскакивает слово "дичь". После "чепухи" идет слово "чепушка": ЧЕПУШКА ж. и чепушок м. вят. силька, цыпля, цыпленок.   

Вот я и подумала, если чепушка - цыпленок, то жарить его на постном масле - занятие глупое, ненужное, бессмысленное, чепуха.

Answer (score 1):

Тут вот какое дело. 
Ответ [[@Соан](/users/169/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BD)](/users/169/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BD) был безупречным, кабы не имеющиеся в сети указания, что это версия небезызвестного выдумщика Валерия Михайловича Мокиенко.
То, что первоначально это некая еда, не вызывает сомнений. А вот насчет того, что это именно *обжаренные* кусочки картофеля...  Это ж почти деликатес.

Пришлось обратиться к Виноградову.

ЧЕПУХА. Слово чепуха родственно словам: чепец, областным причепиться, чепь (см. Соболевский, Лекции, с. 151). Следовательно, современное значение слова чепуха — `нелепость, бессмыслица, чушь' — не является первоначальным. Семантической параллелью к переходу значений может служить слово путаница, которое еще в русском литературном языке XVII—XVIII вв., кроме спутанных веревок, ниток, шелка, еще обозначало в просторечии`враки, пустые слова' (см. сл. АР, 1822, ч. 5, с. 735; ср. у Крылова: «Пока был умный жрец, кумир не путал врак»). Первоначальным же конкретным значением слова чепуха, как указано В. И. Чернышевым21, было: «мелкие части чего-нибудь разбитого» (ср. молотить чепами и молоть чепуху). Как пример такого словоупотребления, В. И. Чернышев приводил цитату из Ломоносова, писавшего: «Льды от ветру в чепуху разбиваются» («Краткое описание путешествий по северным морям», 1854, с. 55).

Т.е. чепуха - «мелкие части чего-нибудь разбитого», вроде вполне подходит для "кусочков картофеля". Но почему просто не назвать жареной картошкой?

Есть и более "продвинутая" версия:

В самом деле, почему чепуха - на постном масле? Да просто потому, что коровье масло: сливочное (чухонское) или сметанное (крестьянское), было дорогим, а постное (льняное или конопляное) - дешёвым. Hа постном масле готовились скудные кушанья для простого люда, понятие "на постном масле" означало второсортность продукта, заведомую дешёвку. То есть, чепуха на постном масле это не просто ерунда, а ерунда сугубая.

Ничего не объясняет однако, кроме того, что это дешевое кушанье. 
А какое у нас кушанье самое дешевое? Правильно, похлебка.
И надоумило меня посмотреть, какие выиды похлебок вообще бывают. 
И вот что я нашел:

~1. От лит. balanda — лебеда. Лебеда, ботва свеклы, идущая на приготовление ботвиньи.  
...
~3. Баланда (рус.) — плохая еда, чаще всего — жидкий суп. Последнее понятие сравнительно недавнее, относится к периоду Первой мировой войны, когда баландой стали называть армейские супы.

А вот и еще значение слова баланда:

Бала́нда (разг.-жарг.): густой невкусный суп;; тюремный суп;; (перен.) вздор, чепуха (травить баланду — пустословить, рассказывать небылицы).
(вики)

Баланда = чепуха (!)
Совпадение выглядит неслучайным. 
Может, чепуха на постном масле - это таки баланда?

Разумеется, пока это не доказательно. Но подумать стоит.