# Какая из версий происхождения слова "чепуха" кажется Вам наиболее достоверной? Почему?

Tags: этимология

Вот прям-таки контаминация невемой чухи со щипаньем? Есть и другие лингвопостройки...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разбирали в вопросе по ссылке http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/Почему-на-постном-масле

Comment: Я изучила тот вопрос. Об этимологии там чуть-чуть: щепа/чепа, чепь/цеп. Что разительно отходит от версии Семёнова, приведённой в подвопросье. Хотелось бы "человечьего" мнения об этом хвостике - уха.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется достоверной версия Галины Цыганенко, вообще люблю читать её словарь.

http://lib.co.ua/dict/cyganenkogp/etimologicheskiyslovarrusskogo.jsp

ЧЕПУХА "вздор, глупость, сущий пустяк" (разг.). Собств. рус.
В памятниках XVIII в. отмечается в знач. "щепки", "крошево". Образовано,
полагают, с пом. суф. -ух-а от несохранившегося *чепа "щепа", "очистки"
- звуков, разновидности к щепа (смешение ч и щ, как в диал. чан.
и щан "кадка большого размера"). Слово *чепа, как и щепа, восходит к
и.-е. *(s)kep-/(s)kop- "резать, чистить" и первонач. значило "очистки, отходы",откуда дальнейшее - "что-либо незначительное" " "сущий пустяк" "
"вздор, глупость" (развитие знач. от конкретного к абстрактному).

От сущ. *чепа с суф. -ур-а (как кожура) образовано утрач. *чепура, давшее с
суф. -ух-а укр. чупуруха "опрятная, аккуратная женщина", с суф. -н- -
. прил. чепурнйй "опрятный, чистый". См. кора, холостой, шелуха, щепа.

Мне сразу вспоминается просторечное (диалектное)"начепурилась" - начистилась, навесила побрякушки,т.е. всякую чепуху, и отправилась завлекать.

Особенно удивило её сближение с "холостой". А что, тот же древний корень - и.-е. *(s)kep-/(s)kop- "резать, чистить".(s)k - ks  - х =хол. Выхолостить - вычистить, вырезать. Холостой - пустой. И патрон, и человек - одинокий-значит, пустой, бесплодный.

Вполне себе версия.

Comment: Начепуриться однокоренное с чепухой! Королева в восхищении!!!

Answer (score 1):

В книге "Почему не иначе?"Л. Успенский, М.1967, говорится следующее: "Будь вы древним, вы могли бы попросить вашего соседа: "Друже, привези мне на двор возов пять твоей чепухи!" - и он бы ничуть не удивился.  В те времена "чепуха" обозначало "щепа", "щепки",поэтому "ч**е**па" значило "щепка". Наверное, поэтому, что щепа тогда считалось вещью бросовой, пустячной; слово "чепуха" и приобрело свое второе, ставшее теперь единственным, значение. Впрочем, это объяснение отнюдь не является единственным, ни бесспорным".